# Connection keep-alive not coming in Response Header - Sitecore 9.0.1 -Windows Server 2016 - GTMetrix report

Tags: iis, performance

I have enabled **allowKeepAlive** setting for my application on IIS by set common header (as shown below) but getting connection as close every time in response header.

[image]

[image]
My application is developed using Sitecore 9.0.1, IIS 10, .Net Framework 4.6.2.

I am not getting what I have missed. Followed the given URL [Enable the HTTP Keep-Alive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772183(v=ws.10))

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's Sitecore 9.1 - I think you mean Sitecore 9.0.1, no?

Comment: @Gatogordo Yes you are right, it is Sitecore XP 9.0.1. It was a typo.

Comment: can you try this by running the following command go to  **%windir%\system32\inetsrv** and run *appcmd.exe* 

To enable the HTTP keep-alive header, use the following syntax:

**appcmd set config /section:httpProtocol /allowKeepAlive:true | false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging a lot and implementing lost of fixes I was advised to check with hosting provider. 
Then I cross checked with hosting provider of the website and found that Keep-Alive was disabled on domain.
By default keep-alive is enabled on server for all domain hosted on that server. 
Posting this as answer for reference in case anybody face the same issue, so can be looked in that direction as well.

Thanks